# Javascript file reader + problem in variable scope

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

i want to read a file in javascript and manipulate some variable so i use this code:

```
var error = false;

var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent){
    var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
    if(textFromFileLoaded.length >=1000){
        error = true;
    }



    console.log(textFromFileLoaded);
};

fileReader.readAsText(uploadFile, "UTF-8");
if(error == true)
    $('#export').prop('disabled', true);
```

in last of code when i try to test if error is true i found it false ( that means that the change of error variable inside the filereader dose not persist .
what is the problem please i need your help.

Answer (score 0):

FileReader.readAsText() is asyncrhoronous so the next line would be executed before the file reading is ready.

You could set the *disabled* property in the event handler.

```
fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent){
    var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
    if(textFromFileLoaded.length >=1000){
        error = true;
        $('#export').prop('disabled', error);
    }
};

fileReader.readAsText(uploadFile, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I added it but the same result the disabled property of button dose not changed

Comment: It works for me. But it doesn't set the attribute for the element it that's what you wanted. You could use attr instead of prop.

Comment: Even when i use the pure javascript document.getElementById('exportResultBtn2').disabled = true;

it dose not work